# Google Play Console Track status production: why isn't the App available?

Tags: android, flutter, google-apps, google-play-console

I uploaded my App a few days ago and today it says "production" under tracks. What exactly does that mean? Before it said "in review".
If I search for my App in the Play Store the App is not shown up, even though it says "available in Google Play" inside my Google Play Console.
Do I have to change any settings or will it be published anyway? I already set it up to be published automatically...
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you set the app to be available in your country and for your device?

Comment: Yes I have chosen 4 countries and one of them is my home country. I have Android 11 and this should work also.

Comment: Did you try through the link of the app?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the link of the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to wait at least 48 hours to 1 week to see your app when you search for it.
try to directly access your app, like this:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=[YOUR APP BUNDEL ID]
```

Or alternatively, click on `view on Google Play` from Google Play Console:

[image]